# Error in checking bluetooth availability in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Code.

```
    BluetoothAdapter ba;
 ba=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {



            if(ba==null)
            {

            }
            else if(ba.isEnabled()==false)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("Settings");
                builder.setMessage("Do you Want to Turn on Bluetooth ?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
                    {
                        Intent m=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {      
                    dialog.cancel();           
                    }      
                });         
                builder.create().show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my code here am trying to check whether the bluetooth is enable or not in a button click. but when i click the button it the application get crashed..

how to solve this? I think the error is , isEnabled() method is returning NULL value.. I am not sure about this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the permissions for accessing bluetooth?

Comment: Yes  I did it like   
<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

Comment: Do we need to add any other permissions other than the above one?

Answer (score -1):

first of all your Code is much easier if you do that so:

```
 BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(ba != null || !ba.isEnabled())
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("Settings");
                builder.setMessage("Do you Want to Turn on Bluetooth ?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
                    {
                        Intent m=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {      
                    dialog.cancel();           
                    }      
                });         
                builder.create().show();
            }
        }
    });
```

So your Problem ws that if you check for null and it is null then you check if it is enabled, but the ba object is null which the code below it must work

Comment: What happens when the ba is not equal to null and ba is enabled then ?

Comment: Nothing, because thers no else clausle :)

Comment: If ba is null then it should pop up with saying : No bluetooth in device

Comment: Yes you can do that, but i only tried to solve the problem which i done.